# Installed python 3.11 instead of 3.8

Tags: python, windows, python-3.8

I wanted to install Python 3.8.14 but it is only available in source code format.

I followed the instructions from [Building Python using the build.bat script](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/PCbuild/readme.txt)

but I ended up with version 3.11:

cmd.exe:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python-3.8.14\externals\pythonx86\tools>python

Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:43:28) [MSC v.1934 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

How to build version 3.8? Should I pass some arguments?

Comment: Do you need 3.8.14 or 3.8.x is fine?

Comment: 3.8.x version is fine

Comment: Downloaded tarball from [python 3.8.14](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3816/) then I followed instructions and launched build.bat file. Then I had something like this in console:

Comment: `...Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'pythonx86.3.11.1' with respect to project 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3.8.14\externals', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Gathering dependency information took 23 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'pythonx86.3.11.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'pythonx86.3.11.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'pythonx86.3.11.1'
Retrieving package 'pythonx86 3.11.1' from 'nuget.org'....`

Comment: looks kind of weird indeed; you might want to add such information to the question. after you finished the build-from-source procedure, if you call `python` in a terminal, do you get a Python 3.11 session?

Comment: what do you have in mind with this build from source, do you want to test changes to the source code or are you looking for a "release" version?

Answer (score 2):

## Use `Python 3.8.10` installers

[Python 3.8.16 download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3816/):

> [this version have] No installers
>
> According to the release calendar specified in PEP 569, Python 3.8 is
> now in the "security fixes only" stage of its life cycle: 3.8 branch
> only accepts security fixes and releases of those are made irregularly
> in source-only form until October 2024. Python 3.8 isn't receiving
> regular bug fixes anymore, and binary installers are no longer
> provided for it. **Python 3.8.10 was the last full bugfix release of
> Python 3.8 with binary installers.**

[Python 3.8.10 download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/)

> This is the tenth and final regular maintenance release of Python 3.8

## Third party installers for 3.8.11+

If you don't mind using third party sources, this page compiles the Pythons with no official windows binary: [github.com/adang1345/PythonWindows](https://github.com/adang1345/PythonWindows)

From [576i](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2335020/576i)

Comment: there still were security fixes, see https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3816/ or https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.8